# Do the following series converge if $a_n>0$ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Do the following series converge if $a_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges ?

a.) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n \over 1+ a_n}$

b.)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n\over 1+ a_n ^2}$

c.)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n\over 1+ na_n }$

d.)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n\over 1+ n^2a_n }$

What I thought was using Alembert criteria , but it just not seem to work. I also now if $a_n$ converges so does $a_n^2$. Ive tried everything to no avail, can anyone please help ?

Comment: You do mean "series" instead of "arrays", right? A good thing to try might be using some well-known divergent series, such as $\sum 1/n$, or $\sum 1$, and seeing what happens. If any of a-d diverge for those (or anything else you can think of), then you know the answer is "no" in general, and you can focus on the remaining series.

Comment: Also, you could try "really" divergent series, such as $\sum n$ or $\sum 2^n$. For instance, if $a_n = n$, then the terms of the first series don't even tend to $0$, so series a.) does not converge.

Comment: last one is definitely converging, since it is less than $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a),  if it is convergent then $a_n/(1+a_n)\to 0$, then $a_n \to 0$, then using

$$a_n \sim \frac{a_n}{1 + a_n}$$

when $a_n\to 0$, then we know $\sum a_n$ must converge, contradiction with $\sum a_n$ diverges.

for (b), it is unknown,

when $a_n = 1/n$, $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2} = \frac{n}{1+n^2} \sim \frac{1}{n}$, thus diverges.

when $a_n = n^2$, $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n^2} = \frac{n^2}{1 + n^4}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}$, converges.

for (c), it is unknown too.

when $a_n = 1/n$, $\frac{a_n}{1 + na_n} = \frac{a_n}{2}$, thus diverges.

think about

$a_n = n$ if $n = k^2$ for some $k\in N$.

$a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for other $n$ which is not a square.

In this case,

$\sum \frac{a_n}{1 + na_n} = \sum_{n\in\{k^2, k\in N\}} \frac{n}{1 + n^2} + \sum_{others} \frac{1}{n^2 + n}$,

first part is equivalent to $\sum_k \frac{k^2}{1+ k^4}$ converges.

second part is equivalent to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2 +n}$ converges.

The last one, each term is less than $1/n^2$, thus converges.

Comment: could you go into more detail into either c or b ?

Comment: I think that you are trying to say that for your given examples, one diverges while the other converges, im not quite seeing that in b. and c. in your answer, could you clarify ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic already clarified

Answer (score 2):

b) It might converge, it might diverge: Look at $a_n = n^2, a_n = 1/n.$

c) It might converge, it might diverge: $a_n = 1/n \implies \sum a_n/(1+na_n) = \infty.$ For an example where $\sum a_n = \infty, \sum a_n/(1+na_n) < \infty,$ define $$\begin{cases} a_{2^m} = 1, m = 1,2,\dots \\a_n = 1/n^2, n \not \in \{2^m: m =1,2,\dots \}\end{cases}$$

Comment: For b.) are you saying that : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n \over n^2 +1}$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^2 \over n^4 +1 }$ doesn't ?

Comment: No, of course not, but I see what you're saying. I'll edit it.